# Send AJAX Corresponding Array Data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Here is my code for a browser extension script. Strings in the names array are highlighted by surrounding them with a span with class=".highlight" using a javascript plugin. The tipped plugin creates tooltips using AJAX data when a user hovers over the highlighted words. A php API library uses AJAX data to create a tooltip that displays information about the given word.

My Code:

```
var names = ["Barack Obama", "Thursday"];
var number = ["N00007360", "N00001817"];
for (var x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
    $("div").highlight(names[x], true);
 }
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Tipped.setDefaultSkin('white');
    Tipped.create(".highlight", "example.php", {
        ajax: { data: { id: "N00007360" }, type: 'post' }
    });
});
```

I am unsure how I would send the corresponding value in the number array in the AJAX data section. As of now, the SAME tooltip is created for all highlighted words - using the id N00007360 which is passed to the php API library. What I need is for the tooltip to send the corresponding string in the number array for each word (names array) hovered over.

Example (what I need): Hover over the word Barack Obama, and the id "N00007360" is sent as AJAX data. Hover over the word Thursday, and the id "N00001817" is sent as AJAX data.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are the arrays connected with each other in the `HTML` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this might work out.

Each object key gets highlighted, then for each highlight class get the text and use that to call the value of the object key

```
var obj = {
    "Barack Obama" : "N00007360",
    "Thursday"     : "N00001817"
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        $("div").highlight(key, true);
    });

    Tipped.setDefaultSkin('white');
    $('.highlight').each(function() {

        var currentKey = $(this).text();
        Tipped.create(this, "example.php", {
            ajax: { data: { id: obj[currentKey] }, type: 'post' }
        });

    });
});
```

If you modify you highlight plugin to allow adding of other html attributes, such as the data attribute, then the hole thing could be even easier, but i guess this might be enough for now

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly :) I was thinking about using a key/value system or modifying the highlight plugin but couldn't figure out how. This is awesome.